# How to add preventDefault in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I just want to add prevenDefault to prevent loading page. Can anyone help me please?

```
<a href="#" onclick ="clickMe()">CLick me</a>
<a href="#" onclick ="clickMe()">CLick me2</a>


 <script>

function clickMe(){
    console.log("working");
}

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `event` to the function as follows:

```js
function clickMe(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("working");
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick ="clickMe(event)">CLick me</a>
<a href="#" onclick ="clickMe(event)">CLick me2</a>
```